# Parsley and jQuery Validate comparison

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

Do you know of a current comparison of Parsley and jQuery Validate?

I have been using the latter for some time but am finding it a bit limited, so am thinking of moving to Parsley.  Parsley seems to be far more current and is in active development.

Before making the move, it would be nice to see a comparison of the two solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Over the last few days I installed Parsley and used it on some of my forms.  I haven't explored it fully, but it seems to be a more comprehensive solution than jQuery Validate.  (No offense to jQuery Validate - it has been a good workhorse, and many of its concepts are echoed in Parsley).

A couple of examples of where I found Parsley easier to work with:

- I needed to have at least one checkbox checked from a group of checkboxes, but only if some other conditions were met first.  I wrote a small custom validator.
- I needed to validate that a tinyMCE field was not empty.  I did this with a one line custom validator.

One of the key features of Parsley is excellent documentation.  In light of this, I am likely to explore and most (if not all) of its features in the future.